# in YII2 how to post data using modal dialog?

Tags: modal-dialog, yii2

I'm using modal dialog. I'm working with two modal. **User Model** and **STATE Model** where
*User* is *Parent model* and *state/create* is open in *modal dialog*.

when I'm creating new User, I have select state name from drop-down, if it is not listed in **dd** then it will create state by clicking add new state and open in modal dialog and create state.

Issue is after create new state parent page is refresh and all the data which I have added are removed.

Kindly guide me. I have created modal dialog by below [link](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/690/render-a-form-in-a-modal-popup-using-ajax/)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand your problem correctly because there is no example code. But if you have separate form to add new state then you can submit that form with ajax using `beforeSubmit`event of `ActiveForm`.

An example of `beforeSubmit`event implementation you can find in this [issue](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/5991)

Also in your controller action you will have to set response type to json like following

```
\Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON;
```

[More info](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-responses.html#response-body) on response types.